# Change edit link URL in the content administration page

Tags: nodes, uri

I been trying to recreate something in the admin section of Drupal from a previous.

In the content, when you roll over the "edit" link. It shows the link like this: https://www.example.com/dolor-melior/edit?destination=admin/content

But I needs it to be: https://www.example.com/node/1/edit?destination=admin/content

I have [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) and [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) modules installed.

Comment: you have installed pathauto? or you set the url alias manually?

Comment: I have pathauto, redirect and global redirect installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `YOUR_SITE/admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk` check ***All aliases*** and click in ***Delete aliases now!***

[image]

Comment: This worked.  I tried to hit the arrow button, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @blackbull77 a pleasure help you, and good luck in your projects ;-)

Comment: Spoke to soon. After I deleted it and try to update the URL alias in the page the title came back again.  :(

Comment: @blackbull77 You must uninstall the pathauto module

Comment: I think got it.  There must be a difference with Acquia Dev Desktop 2 and MAMP because they both render the link differently. Thanks